# Is there a way to have an outer layer of an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE:**

I don't know why I was downvoted, if someone could tell me what I did wrong it would be cool, If you are sure about your answer I could accept a **No** or yes as answer and a simple idea of how to do it.

```css
.gallery {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  min-width: 33%;
  max-width: 33%;
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <!--Images users provide examples:-->
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/300">
  <!--etc...-->
</div>
```

That's ok but I noticed that some images look ugly because they are horizontal images or vertical and I'm giving them a squared shape (I don't like how they look when I give them width/height auto because they all together look disordered and bad).

What I recently did was In another part of the web was to do something like:

```css
.image-cool {
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  min-height: 280px;
  max-height: 280px;
  /*Has a rectangle shape*/
  background: #eee;
}

.image-cool img {
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-cool">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200">
</div>
```

That last code works in the next way:

If you put multiple divs with images inside all will be aligned in the screen and the images will adjust its width and height limited by their container and images don't look bad anymore.

The question here is if I could achieve the same result of the second code in the first code using CSS and without adding more HTML like a div or container.

Why would I not want another div?
Because the current HTML of the first part is essential in that way for some long scripts, Yeah I could modify it all but It will take time and I'm just asking to see if I can save some time.

Thanks a lot for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `img` tag, you can use `background-image` and `background-size: cover` on a `div` therefore any image size can fit into the element.

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/100/300)"></div>
  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/200/100)"></div>
  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/200)"></div>
</div>
```